# Get NullPointerException when use sendbroadcast for GPS location

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gps, location, broadcast

After researching through StackOverflow and not finding answer, I decided to post this question.

I am trying to get my GPS location and broadcasting it to my MainActivity.
In MainActivity I have this:

```
  //get Your Current Location
    LocationManager locationManager=    (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    MyCurrentLocationListener locationListener = new MyCurrentLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) locationListener);
```

And MyCurrentLocationListener looks like this:

```
public class MyCurrentLocationListener extends Activity implements LocationListener {



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();


    String myLocation = "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + location.getLongitude();

    //I make a log to see the results
    Log.e("MY CURRENT LOCATION", myLocation);






    Intent intent_lat=new Intent("loc_lat");
    intent_lat.putExtra("latitud",location.getLatitude());
    sendBroadcast(intent_lat);

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

}

I've been trying lots of things, such as converting the double latitude into String, making my class not extending from activity (but that way I cannot use sendBroadcast).

What shoul I do? If you need more things just tell me.

Thank you.

EDIT: logcat

```
09-30 12:58:47.513 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma    E/MY CURRENT LOCATION: Latitude = 37.18993917 Longitude = -3.60485555
09-30 12:58:47.515 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma, PID: 32019
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:377)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma.MyCurrentLocationListener.onLocationChanged(MyCurrentLocationListener.java:37)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-30 12:58:47.518 32019-32019/com.smartglove.uma.smartgloveuma E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: why don't you implement `LocationListener` in your `MainActivity` itself. This class `MyCurrentLocationListener` extends `Activity`, and why is that?

Comment: show error log from `logcat`

Comment: at first, it didn't extend Activity, but I had to do it to use sendBroadcast (as I couldn't use it, even specifying the context)

Comment: just extending your class with `Activity` won't get you the `Context`. You can get it only in any of its lifecycle methods. example `onCreate()`

Comment: But my class MyCurrentLocationListener doesn't have any onCreate method, should I implement it? I'm sorry but I'm new at Android developement

Comment: Just implement `LocationListener` in your `MainActivity` itself

Comment: send with local broadcast : LocalBroadcastManager broadCast = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this); and registeter it onResume and unregister at onStop . Do this in the mainActivity

Comment: @Boss my `MainActivity` is already implementing `NavigationDrawerCallbacks` , I cannot implement more than one class, can I?

Comment: `LocationListener ` is an interface. You can implement any number of interfaces you want, but you cant extend more than one class

Comment: @Boss it worked!!! thank you so much, I've been fighting against this for a whole week. I also used the code provided by Anton Kovalyov   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `LocationListener` interface in your `MainActivity` and change your code to:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: but my MainActivity already implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks, then it cannot implement a new class